# gnuplot statistics with time data (converted from string as float) fails as single argument

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

I have a data file with time data as one column. Since the `stats` command is not compatible with time data(`Stats command not available in timedata mode`), we have to do some conversion first:

```
set xdata
stats 'data' u (strptime(fmt,strcol(1)))
```

this does not work however. gnuplot prints the following error: `All points out of range`

I don't know why, but I had the idea to use a second artificial column:

```
stats 'data' u (strptime(fmt,strcol(1))):(1.0)
```

This works as intended (**why?**), but with an unnecessary second column. For me, this "workaround" is ok, because I don't have big data files to plot, but if people had... This could be quite annoying.

Did I miss something?
Why does gnuplot stats behaves this way?
Is this a bug, worth reporting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have set an yrange before calling the `stats` command. If you call `stats` with a single column, the data is treated as y-column. In your second call you give an explicit second column, and the time data is treated as x-column.

Calling

```
reset
fmt = "%Y..."
stats 'data' u (strptime(fmt,strcol(1)))
```

should work fine.

Comment: Wow, understanding the error messages is so important. That solved it :D thanks!

Comment: At first I found it counterintuitive, but `plot "data" using 1` also treats this one given column as y-data. In the 5.0 documentation this point was clarified.